# NSAttributedString on currently typed text

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I'm currently making a facebook-like tagging view, i.e. the user types in @name and a view is filtering the names of people which matches the @name. When the user taps a name in that view the currently typed word, in this case @name, will be replaced with the name of the tapped user. For instance, let's say I type @joh I will receive the suggestion "John Doe" which I the proceed to tap. Now @joh is replaced with John Doe. This works fine.

However, I would also like to make "John Doe" a different background color using NSAttributedString, and I have the code to do this as well. The issue I'm experiencing however is that the user might not be done typing and every single character typed after I add the NSBackgroundAttribute causes all the following text receiving the same background color.

I've checked my range for when I add the NSAttribute and it's set to, in this example with John Doe, to be start: 0 and end: 8, but even so I still get the background color on characters that are on a location above 8. What am I missing here?

Code

```
        let tappedUserName = user.name
        let myRange = (textView.text as NSString).rangeOfString(tappedUserName)
        let attribute = [NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blueColor()]
        let myString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textView.text)

        myString.setAttributes(attribute, range: myRange)

        textView.attributedText = myString
```

After this code is executed I continue typing the UITextView's following characters will have the same background color.